# Elliptic Decomposition Theorem

Tags: orthogonality, elliptic-operators, tensor-decomposition

The famous Hodge Decomposition Theorem can be generalized in the context of elliptic operators. The general decomposition theorem can be found in Theorem 5.5 of *Spin Geometry* of H. Blaine Lawson and M.L. Michelsohn as follows:

> **Theorem** Let $(E,M,\pi)$ be a vector bundle and $P:\Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(E)$ be a self-adjoint elliptic operator (respect to a suitable inner product in $\Gamma(E)$). Then we have the orthogonal decomposition:
> $$\Gamma(E)=\ker P\oplus \mathrm{im}\, P.$$

Now, let $(F,M,\pi')$ be another vector bundle. Given $P:\Gamma(E)\to \Gamma(F)$ a (non-elliptic) operator. Then $P\circ P^\star:\Gamma(E)\to \Gamma(F)$ is self-adjoint by construction.

I was wondering if there are any conditions under which we can ensure that the composition $P\circ P^\star$ is elliptic. If so, we would have the following orthogonal decompositions:
$$\Gamma(E)=\mathrm{im}\, P\oplus\ker P^\star$$

Thanks in advance.